# Azure traffic manager and https endpoint

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

I have a Website running on Azure. I added a custom domain and an SSL to enable https access to it.
 All is fine. Few days ago Azure had a network issue in a datacenter where my website is hosted( West Europe) and of course my site was affected during that time. 
So i've decided now to put my site under traffic manager and  deploy it in 2 regions.

Configuring Http acces with ATM works. But when i switch to Https( choosing https protocol in ATM config page) all endpoints get "Degraded" status.

so, my questions are: do i have to add certifcate to traffic manager in order to use https? How can i add https endpoints to ATM?

Comment: You describe several things, but I don't see a clear question. Can you clarify exactly what your question is?

Comment: @DavidEbbo The question is how to configure traffic manager  with https endpoints? as i mentioned i was able to configure it with http access.

Comment: And if you remove your rule, does everything work fine with TM?

Comment: yes , if i remove the rule and choose http protocole in traffic manager configuration page. Everithing works.

Comment: No, I meant if you remove the rule and use https. i.e. trying to find out if the rule has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: In monitor status i get "Degraded". But i can reach my site through TM.

Comment: So you are confirming that your question is not related to the rewrite rule, right? You may want to rephrase it to completely remove that part, as it makes it sound more confusing than it needs to be.

Comment: @DavidEbbo exact. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Traffic Manager supports health probes via both HTTP and HTTPS.  Note that when using HTTPS health checks:

1. The server certificate is not validated (hence there's no need to
   register the certificate with Traffic Manager)
2. Client certificates are not supported
3. SNI certificates are not supported

Please check the above.  Please also check that your monitoring port is configured correctly in Traffic Manager (e.g. 443 instead of 80) and also your monitoring path points to a valid page for your service.

These pages may be helpful:

- [Traffic Manager endpoint monitoring](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-monitoring/)
- [Troubleshooting 'Degraded' endpoint status](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-troubleshooting-degraded/)

If you still can't get it to work, please raise a Support ticket.  If you do solve the problem, please reply back to let us know what it was

Regards,

Jonathan Tuliani, Program Manager, Azure Traffic Manager

Comment: It works now. I needeed to set port 443 instead of 80 in Traffic Manager configuration page. Thank you for your help @jonathan and David

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.  Thanks for letting us know.