# Is it safe not bind CERT to azure traffic manager (in front of HTTPS only app service) host name?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-traffic-manager

Say, I have two app service (HTTPS only is enabled):

```
https://myapp1.azurewebsites.net
https://myapp2.azurewebsites.net
```

I can call both app service endpoints using HTTPS successfully.

Then I created a traffic manager and add above two endpoints to traffic manager, say:

```
myapps.trafficmanager.net
```

After the traffic manager is created and endpoint added, the trafficmanger host name **myapps.trafficmanager.net** is also automatically added into custom domains of two app services. But without SSL binding to traffic manager host name.

Then if I call traffic manager endpoint using HTTPS: https://myapps.trafficmanager.net, I will got untrusted SSL cert error/warning. That is expected.

Since traffic manager just works on DNS level, the real request is actually send to the app service endpoint which has correct SSL cert binding. My question is:

**From security point of view, is it safe to call the non-cert binding traffic manager endpopint using HTTPS in my code (say, using .NET HttpClient)** but just ignore the cert error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to bind a cert with traffic manager since the **server certificate is not validated** when using traffic manager health probes via HTTPS. Moreover, the traffic manager works at the DNS level. The clients connect directly to the selected endpoint, not through Traffic Manager.

In this case, you could use HTTPS for endpoints and use health probe via HTTPS. Even you could not bind a cert with traffic manager, you could make sure that the monitoring port is configured correctly in Traffic Manager (e.g. 443 instead of 80) and also your monitoring path points to a valid page for your service.

[Another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776246/azure-traffic-manager-and-https-endpoint) explains this more details. If you still want to make this warning disappearing, you can get a free SSL from [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/) and add that to your custom domain with the `*.trafficmanager.net`.

Comment: yes I have configure the probe protocol to HTTPS and port to 443. And I can get the result successfully from https://myapps.trafficmanager.net except the untrusted cert warning. I just want to make sure it is safe to use HTTPS trafficmanager endpont and ignore the cert warning from security point of view.

Comment: I think it's safe since the client directly connects to the selected endpoint, not through traffic manager. Also, the HTTPS data transaction happens above the DNS level.

Answer (score 2):

I recently set one of these up as well and fought with it for a bit. The short answer is that it is probably safe, but it sounds like you may be using the Traffic Manager incorrectly. You shouldn't be using the URL in the Traffic Manager as your end point if you want to use SSL. Instead configure your vanity domain name, `mycoolsite.com` to point to `myapps.trafficmanager.net`, using a DNS CNAME record.

If you want to use SSL and a single URL you should configure the custom URL and install an SSL cert at the service level. It should be same custom URL on both app services. This must be configured at in the app service, [not in Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs).

I had to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-how-it-works) a few times to understand how it works under the hood, but it was helpful.

So in summary, to set it up properly, the steps would be:

1. Configure custom/vanity domain on both app services
2. Install the SSL cert on both app services
3. Setup and configure the Traffic Manager
4. Point the custom/vanity URL to the traffic manager using a DNS CNAME record